# mysql, getting results from two tables. Missing one row

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables in my database..

Users and guestbook

UserTable:
userID, username, password, email

GuestbookTable:
gbID, userID, toID, text, date

I'm trying to get the userInfo from users with $_GET['userID']

And then im trying to get all the entries in the guestbook by toID = $_GET['userID']

I use this code right now

```
$sql = "SELECT u1.*, g.text AS entry_text, g.date AS guestbook_date, u2.userID AS from_userID, u2.username AS from_username
FROM users AS u1
LEFT JOIN guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.toID
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON g.userID = u2.userID
WHERE u1.userID = :id

";
```

And it kinda works.. The only problem i got with this right now is that the first message sent in the guestbook is missing on the website but still in the database.

I did a db fiddle of this
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4xartd2hGXQZHuNmqgSiMW/0

And i don't get the same problem as on my website..

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the fiddle i figured out that there is no problems with the query code its problems with the PHP code that handles this..

```
<?php 
            $thisId = intval($_GET['userID']);
$sql = "
    SELECT
        u1.*,
        g.text AS entry_text,
        g.date AS guestbook_date,
        u2.userID AS from_userID,
        u2.username AS from_username
    FROM
        users AS u1
    LEFT JOIN
        guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.toID
    INNER JOIN
        users AS u2 ON u2.userID = g.userID 
    WHERE
        u1.userID = :userId
    ORDER BY
        g.date DESC;";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':userId', $thisId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

            $userData = $db->fetchAssoc($stmt);
            if (empty($userData)) { 
                echo '<div class="column"><h2><span class="blue">PLAY.</span> Profil ej hittad</h2><div class="alert-error">Användaren du försökte hitta finns ej i vårat system...</div></div>';
            }
            else { 
                echo '<div class="column column-60">';
                echo '<h2><span class="radius"><span class="blue">PLAY.</span> Profil</span></h2>';
                echo '<div class="UserTitle">'.$userData['username'].' </div>';
                echo '<div class="Content">'; 
                echo '<div class="ImageBox"><img src="/img/users/1.png"></div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="column column-40">'; 
                echo '<h2><span class="radius"><span class="blue">PLAY.</span> Gästbok</span></h2>';
                if (empty($userData['entry_text'])) {
                        echo '<div class="alert-error">Tyvärr så har inte '.$userData['username'].' några gästboksinlägg :(</div>'; 
                }
                else { 
                echo '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="GuestBook">';
                 while ($row = $db->fetchAssoc($stmt)) {    
                    var_dump($row);
                    echo '<br><br>';
                    echo '<tr><td width="60" valign="top"><div class="ImageBox"><img src="/img/users/1.png"></div></td><td valign="top"><div class="Title"><a href="/user/'.$row['from_userID'].'">'.$row['from_username'].'</a> - '.date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($row['guestbook_date'])).'</div><div class="Content">'.$row['entry_text'].'</div></td></tr>';
                }
                echo '</table>';
                echo '<div class="pagination"></div>';
                }
                if ($userID != $thisId) { echo '<form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="toID" value="'.$thisId.'"><textarea name="text" placeholder="Skriv ett meddelande..."></textarea><input type="submit" name="addGB" value="Skicka" class="btn-blue"></form>'; }
                echo '</div>';
            }
            $db->close();
        ?>
```

If i change the while statement and put on the top before the $userData var i get all the entries from the database. If i put it after the userData var i miss one entry from the database.

Comment: Without sample data this is always going to involve a certain amount of guesswork

Comment: The question is if its better to make a PHP function and retrieve the username from the poster instead of joining the table again to get his username

Comment: Actually I meant show us the source data from the tables not the results of the query. That way, we can more easily work out the best way of writing the query. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: @Tommy please construct your issue on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT) . See[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3

Comment: Ah thank you! I fix this when im on the computer again

Comment: perhaps the links are the wrong way round maybe - LEFT JOIN guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.toID LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON g.userID = u2.userID  should be LEFT JOIN guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.userid LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON g.toid = u2.userID

Answer (score 1):

to get the user information and all the entries in the guestbook with toID = $_GET['userID'], you can try using a SQL query that combines the two tables correctly. Also, you may want to sort the guestbook entries by date. Here is an example of how you might do this:

```
    // Assume that $_GET['userID'] contains the ID of the user you want to query

$userId = $_GET['userID'];

$sql = "
    SELECT
        u1.*,
        g.text AS entry_text,
        g.date AS guestbook_date,
        u2.userID AS from_userID,
        u2.username AS from_username
    FROM
        users AS u1
    LEFT JOIN
        guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.toID
    LEFT JOIN
        users AS u2 ON g.userID = u2.userID
    WHERE
        u1.userID = :userId
    ORDER BY
        g.date DESC;";

// Execute the SQL query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

// Get the results
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Now, $results will contain the user information and guestbook entries
```

Comment: This does the same thing as my posted code does.. And the order date DESC removes the last posted message, so instead of 10 i got 9 posts

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN` might be causing issues with how the results are fetched.

Consider using a straightforward `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
$sql = "SELECT u1.*, g.text AS entry_text, g.date AS guestbook_date, u2.userID AS from_userID, u2.username AS from_username
FROM users AS u1
LEFT JOIN guestbook AS g ON u1.userID = g.toID
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON g.userID = u2.userID
WHERE u1.userID = :id";
```

Comment: Ah sorry missed that i changed  it... I have the same problem if i do left join